# Android - multiple launcher - one for nfc tag and another for normal launcher

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, nfc

I need to implement multiple launcher in my appication. When i am touch the tag in device i want to start the application from one activity and when i click on the application icon i want to start the application from another activity. Can anybody know how to do this?

Thanks
Mindus

Answer (score 0):

Add Launcher tag in both of activity declaration in your manifest file.